# Is matrix size in bigmemory library limited by "max vector size" in R?

Tags: r, vector, r-bigmemory

we have a big matrix that can not fit in bigmemory, because it exceeds the max_vector_size, is there a way to solve this?

`a = matrix(rnorm(200e6 * 15), 200e6)
b = as.big.matrix(a, backingfile="")
Error in SetMatrixElements(x@address, as.double(j), as.double(i), as.double(value)) : 
  long vectors not supported yet: ../include/Rinlinedfuns.h:138
Error during wrapup: long vectors not supported yet: ../include/Rinlinedfuns.h:138`

Thank you. JC

Comment: We found a work-around. We first create a big.matrix, then copy over the elements from data by pieces smaller than the max vector size. But it would be better if bigmemory can handle this.

Comment: If you're using only filebacked `big.matrix` you could use package **bigstatsr**, which have a similar format as **bigmemory**. Using `big_copy(a)` will do create the matrix and fill it by blocks for you. (disclaimer: I'm the author)